# Reference Variable Calling Destructor

Tags: c++, variables, reference, singleton, destructor

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Singleton
{
public:
    // GetInstance returns an instance to an existing Singleton object
    static Singleton& GetInstance()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Singleton()
    {
        std::cout << "Singleton destructor" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    // Private constructor
    Singleton()
    {
        std::cout << "Singleton constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Singleton mySingleton = Singleton::GetInstance();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Singleton constructor
Singleton destructor
Singleton destructor
```

It appears that the reference variable `mySingleton` is being cleaned up, thus calling the destructor twice.
Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a copy of the instance here:

```
Singleton mySingleton = Singleton::GetInstance();
```

You want to make the copy constructor and assignment operator private too, that will force you to take a reference:

```
Singleton& mySingleton = Singleton::GetInstance();
```

Comment: Good catch! My mistake, forgot to declare (and not define) the copy constructor otherwise this would've been pointed out straight away. Cheers :)